# problema al Imprimir datos con el ciclo foreach

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

estoy desarrollando un ecomerce y tengo el siguiente problema al llenar el carrito de compras les comparto el codigo y el problema que tengo.

este es el ajax que realiza las consultas:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    //AJAX que llena el carrito
    $.ajax({
        url: 'consultasAjax/leerCarrito.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            llenarCarrito(response);
            llenarTablaCarrito(response);

        }
    });
    
    
    //llamando el evento click de esta forma se corrije el error que produce que cuando quieras agregar directamente 
    // los productos de los catalogos solo se agregaba el primero y en el resto de productos no funciionaba los botones.
    $(document).on("click","#agregarCarrito",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("hola");
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
        var img = $(this).data('img');
        var carpeta = $(this).data('carpeta');
        var rubro = $(this).data('rubro');
        var precio = $(this).data('precio');
        var cantidad = $('#cantidad_prod').val();
         $.ajax({
                        url: 'consultasAjax/agregar_carrito.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {"id":id,"nombre":nombre,"img":img,"carpeta":carpeta,"rubro":rubro,"precio":precio,"cantidad":cantidad},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response) {
                            llenarCarrito(response);
                            $('#badge_c_compras').fadeIn('slow/400/fast').fadeOut('slow/400/fast').fadeIn('slow/400/fast');
                            
                        }
        }); 
    });
    //funcion que llena la tabla del carrito
    function llenarTablaCarrito(response){
        //recoremos todos los elementos de los productos para imprimirlos en la lista del carrito
        var cantidad_prod = Object.keys(response).length;
        console.log("Productos:"+cantidad_prod);
        response.forEach(function(element) {
            var totalproductos=element['cantidad']*element['precio'];
            
            $('#tablaCarrito').append(
                `
                    <tr>
                        
                        <td><img src="dist/images/${element['carpeta']}/${element['img']}" class="img-size-50" alt=""></td>
                        <td>${element['nombre']}</td>
                        <td>${element['cantidad']}</td>
                        <td>${element['precio']}</td>
                        <td>${totalproductos}</td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></td>
                    </tr>                     
                    
                `
                
            );
        });
    };

    function llenarCarrito(response){
        //Capturamos la catidad de objetos dentro de la COOKIE productos
        var cantidad_prod = Object.keys(response).length;
        if (cantidad_prod>0) {
            $('#badge_c_compras').text(cantidad_prod);
            
        }
        else{
            $('#badge_c_compras').text('');

        }
        //borramos la lista del carrito antes de llenarla
        $('#carritoCompras').text('');

        //recoremos todos los elementos de los productos para imprimirlos en la lista del carrito
        response.forEach(element => {
                        $('#carritoCompras').append(
                `
                    <a href="panelTienda.php?departamento=detalle_p&id=${element['id']}&rubro=${element['rubro']}" class="dropdown-item">
                        <!-- Message Start -->
                        <div class="media">
                          <img src="dist/images/${element['carpeta']}/${element['img']}"width="128" height="128"  alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
                          <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="dropdown-item-title">
                              ${element['nombre']}
                              <span class="float-right text-sm text-danger"><i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                              </span>
                            </h2>
                            <p class="text-sm">cantidad: ${element['cantidad']}</p>
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Message End -->
                      </a>
                      
                      
                `
            );
        });
        //Añadimos el boton de vaciar carrito
        $('#carritoCompras').append(
                `
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a href="panelTienda.php?departamento=verCarrito" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer text-info" id="verCarrito">
                        Ver Carrito 
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
                      </a>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer text-danger" id="borrarCarrito">
                        Vaciar Carrito 
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                `
        );
    }
    $(document).on("click","#borrarCarrito",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'consultasAjax/BorrarCarrito.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                llenarCarrito(response);
                
            }
        });
    });


});
```

este es el archivo php que agrega los productos al carrito:

```
<?php 
    $productos=unserialize(isset($_COOKIE['productos'])?$_COOKIE['productos']:'');


    if (is_array($productos)==false) {
        $productos=array();
    }
    $existeProducto=false;
    foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
        if($value['id']==$_REQUEST['id']){
            $productos[$key]['cantidad']+=$_REQUEST['cantidad'];
            $existeProducto=true;
        }
    }

    if ($existeProducto==false) {
        
        $nuevo_producto=array(
            "id"=>$_REQUEST['id'],
            "nombre"=>$_REQUEST['nombre'],
            "img"=>$_REQUEST['img'],
            "carpeta"=>$_REQUEST['carpeta'],
            "cantidad"=>$_REQUEST['cantidad'],
            "rubro"=>$_REQUEST['rubro'],
            "precio"=>$_REQUEST['precio']
        );
        array_push($productos, $nuevo_producto);
    }   
    setcookie("productos",serialize($productos));
    
    echo json_encode($productos);
    




?>
```

y este otro archivo php es donde leo los productos para llenar el carrito y la tabla de productos del carrito:

```
<?php 
    $productos=unserialize(isset($_COOKIE['productos'])?$_COOKIE['productos']:'');
    
    echo json_encode($productos);


?>
```

mi problema es que al momento de llenar la tabla de productos con los mismos productos con los que se llena el carrito me lo imprime DOS VECES. e incluso imprimi una variable con la cantidad de objetos que tiene el json y me sale la cantidad que deveria de mostrar. espero me puedan ayudar. aca les dejo una foto para ver si me explico mejor[image: detalles de producto]

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda resumir tu pregunta para que todos puedan entender el problema que tienes, como incluir solo el código donde crees que puede estar tu problema, retroalimentar tu pregunta con tus avances, referencias, investigaciones, etc. Esto aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad y además ayudarás a que a la comunidad le sea de utilidad tu pregunta para cuando tengan un problema similar al tuyo.